# deployment of dotnet7 on redhat7 using nginx

Tags: .net-core, curl, redhat

I am having an issue with dotnet 7 deployment on redhat7 server. i have installed dotnet7 SDK using the binary codes, created a simple asp.net mvc application , published and run it everything is fine.
Now when i try curl `curl http://127.0.0.1:5161` or `curl http://localhost:5161` i am getting this error: `curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:5161; Connection refused` i dont know why its refusing the curl, i am using nginx  as proxy. i have opened the port 5161 but no luck.
this command is showing nothing : `netstat -tlpen | grep 5161`.

this is my program cs file:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

also my application is published on this : `/var/www/dotnet/bin/Release/net7.0`
can someone help me on this

thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is the port when you `dotnet run` without nginx? does that port work?

Comment: Hello @QiangFu the port is 5161, but i notice that when i run with dotnet run myapp.dll and open another console curl is working and i can also access to my app on the browser. now i am having the service issue. its should run automatically but the service is not.  "sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/dotnetservicefile.service"

Comment: How about add chmod 777 to that service file.

Comment: ok i can try that, but i think the issue might come from the service conf:         =====    [Unit]
Description=Running ASP.NET Core 7.0 on RHEL 7.0
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/dotnet/public
ExecStart=/var/www/dotnet/public/dotnet.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=nginx
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target